# Aggregation vs Composition in OOP (Java example)

Tags: java, oop, uml, aggregation, composition

Now I understand the theory of these types of associations:

- Aggregation implies a relationship where the child can exist independently of the parent. Example: Class (parent) and Student (child). Delete the Class and the Students still exist.
- Composition implies a relationship where the child cannot exist independent of the parent. Example: House (parent) and Room (child). Rooms don't exist separate to a House.

But it's difficult for me to understand how it works in practice.

So far this is my understanding and I would be glad if someone could correct me if I am wrong

```java
// A simple separate class called Address
public class Address {

    private String address;

    public Address(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
}
```

```java
// And a person class that has address field
public class Person {
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private Address address;

    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
        ....
}
```

I think this type of association is `aggregation` because **I have to** set the address from client code  so Address class hypothetically lives without a Person. Heres how it would look like:

```java
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Address address = new Address("308 Negra Arroyo Lane, Albuquerque, New Mexico");
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setAddress(address);
                // address object still lives without person object and I can reuse it
    }
}
```

On the other hand this seems like an `composition` to me, since the Address class is instantiated within the Person class and it doesn't exist anywhere else (It's bound to one specific class)

```java
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private Address address;
    
    public Person() {
        address = new Address("308 Negra Arroyo Lane, Albuquerque, New Mexico");
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
        ....
}
```

And here's a client app

```java
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.getAddress();
                // address object has no meaning outside of Person class
    }
}
```

Atleast that's how I understand the concept, I may be wrong tho so I'd like if someone experienced could confirm this (or correct me if am wrong). Also the main reason why I do this is to write efficient UML so any thought of that would be appreciated too

Comment: composition IS a form of aggregation. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/association-composition-aggregation-java/